# When are new connections allowed after limit of 100 concurrent connection is reached in firebase?

Tags: firebase

According to the website they have a limit of  100 concurrent connections in  the free plan but when 101th connection tries to connect it is refused, so when the new connections are allowed?

For example : do the users have to wait for certain time period or as soon as one connection is closed ,the other is given the chance to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of the existing connections disappears, the next incoming connection will be allowed.

So if you have a chat application and there are 100 active users in the chat room, the next user won't be able to join and the Firebase client will throw an error (LIMIT_EXCEEDED) when they try. If one of the active users leaves (disconnects, closes their browser tab, etc), the next user will be allowed to connect.