# Confusion related to firebase realtime database pricing model

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to use firebase for a project. The use case scenario is such that there might be situations (sometimes - may be 5 to 6 times in a month) that the simultaneous connections to 'Realtime Database' exceed 100 - the limit for the free plan.

Quoting from their pricing faq -

> What happens if I exceed Spark or Flame plan storage or download
>   limits for Realtime Database?
>
> To provide you with a predictable price, the resources available to
>   you in the Spark and Flame plans are capped. This means that when you
>   exceed any plan limit in any month, your app will be turned off to
>   prevent any further resource usage and additional charges.

---

> What happens if I exceed Spark plan simultaneous connection limits for
>   Realtime Database?
>
> Usage is measured monthly, and if your app is disabled in a given
>   month because of usage, it is automatically re-enabled at the
>   beginning of the next month.

So my question is - say at a time 'T' my app exceeds 100 simultaneous connections to the Realtime Database by 'n' users. Will this mean that -

1) My application will be shut down for the rest of the month and no further connections to the real-time database will be possible for that entire month?

OR

2) The first 100 active connections will work and the 'n' users trying to connect after the 100-mark will not be able to connect until some one from the first 100 disconnects?

Comment: Good catch. That looks like a copy/paste mistake in the FAQ. As Vivek answered: when you reach the maximum number of simultaneous connections, the app keeps working but stops accepting new connections. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786933/when-are-new-connections-allowed-after-limit-of-100-concurrent-connection-is-rea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application will not get suspended or shut down if you exceed the limit.

When you have 100 users connected to your real time database, the database stops accepting new connections. But as soon as one of the existing user disconnects, the database will accept the new connection again in this process the number of simultaneous connections will never exceed 100.

When you upgrade your project to a paid plan, the connection limit is immediately raised.

Comment: do you know how much it increases the price on blaze plan when you exceed 100 clients and let say you have 1000 clients connected at the same time? Thanks