# Firebase: exceeded maximum peak of simultaneous database connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What could happen if the number of concurrent connections would be more than the maximum of the chosen pricing plan? Will the users experience a performance slowdown, though still working, or a complete denial of service?
For example, the connected users are 100, will the numbers 101, 102, 103, etc be put in a queue and still be able to download data after a short delay?
From my point of view, as developer, what event or callback should I manage in this case?

I'd like to know its behaviour in the last versions, is there an official guide that explain what that means? I've already found questions but they were outdated.

The [guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing) I found says

> What happens if I exceed Spark plan simultaneous connection limits for Realtime Database?
>
> Usage is measured monthly, and if your app is disabled in a given month because of usage, it is automatically re-enabled at the beginning of the next month.

Is it a complete denial of service? After the peak is exceeded the project will be suspended until the end of the month?

Comment: from the docs it looks like the limit is usage base not the client connection base

Comment: There is a mistake in the documentation. Sorry about that. This was reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847301/confusion-related-to-firebase-realtime-database-pricing-model#comment78665684_45847301) a few days ago, and we're working on getting it fixed. The behavior is as described in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786933/when-are-new-connections-allowed-after-limit-of-100-concurrent-connection-is-rea.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you know how much it increases the price on blaze plan when you exceed 100 clients and let say you have 1000 clients connected at the same time? Thanks

Comment: Pricing is not based on the number of connected clients, but on the amount of data you store, and the amount of data you read from the database.