# Firebase Connections Dilema (case study)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know people have been asking this question .. I sure did search and read a lot but I'm still frustrated.

I have an app created whit React and Firebase (online assessment/quiz) ... its expected .. when it's released, the first days to have up too 120/90 people using it and the following days fewer people 10/20 using it .. I see the connections I have in firebase console are 100 max. I see the graph of daily usage .. for now, it someday 4, someday 2, someday 1 ... cuz I'm testing on my devices... But why does

> Connections
>
> 4 / 100 peak

stays at  4/100 when today, for instance, I have only 1 connection ... this leads me to my questions...

1. Will the database shutdown after the first 100 people(devices) connect to it and use the app to submit the result?

or

2. Will the database still work as long as 100 connections per day are not passed?

Comment: The Firebase Database will work for the first 100 people to connect to it concurrently. When user 101 tries to connect, they get rejected. When one of the existing users disconnects, the next user is allowed to connect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786933/when-are-new-connections-allowed-after-limit-of-100-concurrent-connection-is-rea

Comment: Note that this is not a *daily* limit, but a *concurrent* limit. There is no limit on the number of users that can connect during a day, but on the free plan only 100 users can connect *simultaneously*.

Comment: In my case .. people will go on this page fivecmodelassessment.github.io .. submit a result to the database ( only using `set()` ) and will they count as a connection if I redirect then after the submitting to some other www page ... or when I do `this.database.ref().off()`

Comment: If they're not on your page, they won't count as a connection.

Comment: Nice... Just  one more question ... will react router .. if I use <Redirect />  will this count as a page change or i have to change the domain itself ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you answer this question for me, please. Tomorrow i need to  present this project :D

Comment: I don't know enough about react router to answer that. But if you check the Web Sockets panel in the Network tab of your browser you can see if there is still a connection from your web page to the Firebase servers.